# Strtok using dynamic memory

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, strtok

I have the following code, and I need help getting and storing the last token. Right now the code tokenizes after every space, but when it gets to the end of my text file, it doesn't tokenize the last value. I'm pretty sure I need to have the token before the malloc statements, but when I add it in front, I get a seg fault. Does anybody know the issue? Initialized  `myStruct.extras = NULL` above because of `realloc`; it is a `char **`.

```
token = strtok(fileArrayPTR[p],"X");
while (token!= NULL)
{   

    if (tempCounter == 0)
    { 
        token = strtok(NULL," "); 
        myStruct.dimensions[1] = strtol(token,&ptr,10);
    }else{
        myStruct.extras = realloc(myStruct.extras,(extraCounter + 1) * sizeof(char *)); 
        myStruct.extras[extraCounter] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);  
        strcpy(myStruct.extras[extraCounter],token);
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        extraCounter++;
    }
}
```

edit: forgot to put the incremented counter

Comment: Where do you increment `extraCounter`?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that in. I have it at the end after the token

Comment: @BeginnerC96   Is the string zero-terminated? For the debug  purpose try to calculate its  length using strlen.

Comment: No, I haven't terminated anything. Where would I put that in? Is that just token[strlen(token)-1] = '\0' ?

Comment: Post more of the initialization for the loop.  If we can see how the original string is read in, how you initialize token and extraCounter at least, then that would be good.  Also, how is myStruct.extras initialized?

Comment: @BeginnerC96  I mean the string that you split into tokens.

Comment: It is really hard for us to debug your code when you don't give us an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  If you created an MCVE, you might well solve your problem while developing it.  Failing that, it is easy for us to see where the problem is.  See also SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — an alternative but equivalent idea to MCVE.

Comment: Sorry, added the code above it. Basically the first two strtoks of my text file, get stored into a dimension array, and then the rest should get stored into the extras array. The text file would be 10X16 "space" something "space" something

Comment: So you say it only misses the last token in the input file? Then the problem might be in how you're reading the input.  As Jonathan says, you should post a minimal example that reproduces the problem; include an example input file (hopefully only a couple lines are needed in the repro).  Also check whether the last line ends with a newline and whether or not the newline being there matters.

Comment: Why have you started with the delimiter for `strtok()` as `"X"` then on iteration used `" "` ? And in the code block `if (tempCounter == 0)` you called `strtok()` again, before processing the previous.

Comment: Where do you increment `tempCounter`?  If it stays zero, you have problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is (the second version of) the code from the question:

```
token = strtok(fileArrayPTR[p],"X");
while (token!= NULL)
{   
    if (tempCounter == 0)
    { 
        token = strtok(NULL," "); 
        myStruct.dimensions[1] = strtol(token,&ptr,10);
    }else{
        myStruct.extras = realloc(myStruct.extras,(extraCounter + 1) * sizeof(char *)); 
        myStruct.extras[extraCounter] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);  
        strcpy(myStruct.extras[extraCounter],token);
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        extraCounter++;
    }
}
```

This is not a self-contained program.  We can improve it by:

- Removing the structure.
- Showing corresponding variable declarations.
- Converting it into a simple `main()`.

Those changes lead to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int extraCounter = 0;
    char **extras = 0;
    int tempCounter = 0;
    char *ptr = 0;
    char data[] = "10X16 something another-thing";
    char *token = strtok(data, "X");
    int dimension1 = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
    int dimension2 = -1;
    while (token!= NULL)
    {   
        if (tempCounter == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL," "); 
            dimension2 = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
            tempCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            extras = realloc(extras, (extraCounter + 1) * sizeof(char *)); 
            extras[extraCounter] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);  
            strcpy(extras[extraCounter], token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            extraCounter++;
        }
    }

    printf("Dimensions: %dx%d\n", dimension1, dimension2);
    for (int i = 0; i < extraCounter; i++)
        printf("%d: [[%s]]\n", i, extras[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

And when run, it produces:

```
Dimensions: 10x16
0: [[16]]
1: [[something]]
2: [[another-thing]]
```

Is there a problem with that code?  Yes, the code for the `dimension2` doesn't reinvoke `strtok()`, so `16` is processed twice, once as a dimension and once as a string.  Probably not what's wanted.  Hence:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int extraCounter = 0;
    char **extras = 0;
    int tempCounter = 0;
    char *ptr = 0;
    char data[] = "10X16 something another-thing";
    char *token = strtok(data, "X");
    int dimension1 = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
    int dimension2 = -1;
    while (token !=  NULL)
    {
        if (tempCounter == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            dimension2 = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
            tempCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            extras = realloc(extras, (extraCounter + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            extras[extraCounter] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(extras[extraCounter++], token);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("Dimensions: %dx%d\n", dimension1, dimension2);
    for (int i = 0; i < extraCounter; i++)
        printf("%d: [[%s]]\n", i, extras[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -g -O3 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror ss.c -o ss
```

Output:

```
Dimensions: 10x16
0: [[something]]
1: [[another-thing]]
```

Looks better...